# How can a Selenium script be converted into the equivalent plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, translation

How can a Selenium script be converted into the equivalent plain Javascript?

Comment: @epascarello I am new to selenium, I'll make it IDE as I am using it with Firefox

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that we dont have an IDE to JavaScript converter but we are happy to take a patch if you create one.

The best way is to create the test from scratch by hand and then use it. [Soda](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda) is a great javascript runner for Selenium using JavaScript on Node.js

Comment: I thought Selenium works by executing the Javascript that is equivalent to user clicks and keyboard presses. Don't such steps have a direct Javascript equivalent?